# Quotient of semi-simple rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

I can't seem to find a reference for the following statement:

> A quotient ring of a (left) semi-simple ring (left artinian with no nonzero nilpotent ideals) is a semi-simple ring.

Does this follow from quotients of semi-simple modules being semi-simple?

A quotient ring of a left artinian ring is left artinian. So we only have to show that the quotient contains no nonzero nilpotent ideals. I'm looking for something more low-level than $\text{rad}(R/I) = \text{rad}(R) + I$, which I seem to remember to be true. Can I somehow use the characteristic that every left ideal is generated by an idempotent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow use the characteristic that every left ideal is generated by an idempotent element?

Yes, that is a good approach. Let $T$ be a right ideal of $R$ containing $I$ properly. Then $T\setminus I$ contains a nonzero idempotent, and $e+I\in (T+I)^n$ shows that no right ideal is nilpotent.

Alternatively, you could use the Artin-Wedderburn theorem to note that an ideal is a product of simple components, and the quotient is the complementary set of simple components.

Alternatively you could note that $R$ and all of its quotients are Von Neumann regular, and an Artian VNR ring is semisimple.

Answer (score 0):

You can also imitate the proof for the quotient module.

For convenience of writing, let $\pi: R\to R/I$ be the canonical projection. Given $\mathfrak{a}$ a left ideal in $\pi(R)$, let $A=\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})$. Then $A$ is a left ideal in $R$. By hypothesis $R$ is semisimple, and therefore exists $B$ a left ideal, $A\oplus B=R$.

We claim $\pi(R)=\pi(A)\oplus\pi(B)\ (=\mathfrak{a}\oplus\pi(B)\ )$. In fact

- $\pi(R)=\pi(A)+\pi(B)$: Given $r\in R$, since $R=A\oplus B$, exists $a\in A,\ b\in B$ s.t. $r=a+b$. $\implies\pi(r)=\pi(a+b)=\pi(a)+\pi(b)$.
- The sum is direct: Assume $a\in A,\ b\in B$, $\pi(a)=\pi(b)$. Then $\pi(a-b)=0\implies a-b\in I=\pi^{-1}(0)\subseteq \pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})=A$. That is exists $a_0\in A$ s.t. $ a-b=a_0$. Therefore $b=a-a_0\in A$. Since $b\in B$ and $A\cap B=(0)$ (Recall $R=A\oplus B$), we have $b=0$, i.e. $\pi(a)=\pi(b)=0$.

Provided that $B$ is a left ideal in $R$,
it is easy to check $\pi(B)$ is a left ideal of $\pi(R)$. Therefore $\mathfrak{a}$, an arbitrary left deal in $\pi(R)$, is a direct summand of $_{\pi(R)}\pi(R)$, i.e. $\pi(R)$ is a semisimple ring.